# How do I create a cron job to run an postgres SQL function?

Tags: sql, linux, function, postgresql, cron

I assume that all I need to do is to:

1. Create an sql file e.g. nameofsqlfile.sql contents:

   perform proc_my_sql_funtion();
2. Execute this as a cron job.

However, I don't know the commands that I'd need to write to get this cron job executed as a postgres function for a specified host,port,database, user & his password...?

Answer (score 20):

You just need to think of cronjob as running a shell command at a specified time or day.

So your first job is to work out how to run your shell command.

```
psql --host host.example.com --port 12345 --dbname nameofdatabase --username postgres < my.sql
```

You can then just add this to your crontab (I recommend you use `crontab -e` to avoid breaking things)

```
# runs your command at 00:00 every day
#
# min hour wday month mday command-to-run
    0    0    *     *    * psql --host host.example.com --port 12345 --dbname nameofdatabase < my.sql
```

Answer (score 4):

In most cases you can put all of the sql source in a shell 'here document'. The nice thing about here documents is that the shell's ${MY_VAR} are expanded *even within single quotes*, e.g:

```
#!/bin/sh

THE_DATABASE=personnel
MY_TABLE=employee
THE_DATE_VARIABLE_NAME=hire_date
THE_MONTH=10
THE_DAY=01

psql ${THE_DATABASE} <<THE_END
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${MY_TABLE}
  WHERE ${THE_DATE_VARIABLE_NAME} >= '2011-${THE_MONTH}-${THE_DAY}'::DATE
THE_END
```

YMMV

Answer (score 2):

Check this

http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-admin/2000-10/msg00026.php
and
http://www.dbforums.com/postgresql/340741-cron-jobs-postgresql.html

or you can just create a bash script to include your coding and call it from crontab

Answer (score 2):

For Postgresql 10 and above you can use [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron). As stated in its README.md,

> pg_cron is a simple cron-based job scheduler for PostgreSQL (10 or higher) that runs inside the database as an extension. It uses the same syntax as regular cron, but it allows you to schedule PostgreSQL commands directly from the database: