# postgres copy path from full path with linux command

Tags: postgresql, path, copy, quotes, double-quotes

I'm trying to get a path from a full path and copi it in a new column but I have a hard time managing quotes.
 I have a column with "/volume2/test/here it is/my file.avi" and I want to copy in another column just "my file.avi" 
(I'd also like the path but I'l check that after )
can somebody help?

```
/usr/bin/psql -U postgres video_metadata -q -A -t -c \"""SELECT RIGHT(path, POSITION('\' in REVERSE(path)) -1 ) from video_file;""\""
```

but I have this error

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

If I try something cleaner like

```
/usr/bin/psql -U postgres video_metadata -q -A -t -c "SELECT RIGHT(path, POSITION('\' in REVERSE(path)) -1 ) from video_file;"
```

I have this error

```
ERROR:  unterminated quoted string at or near "'\' in REVERSE(path)) -1 ) from video_file;"
LINE 1: SELECT RIGHT(path, POSITION('\' in REVERSE(path)) -1 ) from ...
```

Comment: What's the problem with: `psql -U postgres video_metadata -q -A -t -c "SELECT RIGHT(path, POSITION('\' in REVERSE(path)) -1 ) from video_file;"`?

Comment: You have 3 double-quotes in the beginning and 4 in the end, that is the problem. Btw, is there any special reason for you to escape double-quotes `\"` on a linux console?

Comment: why have you got '\' in your paths?

Comment: I have a column with a full path like "/volume2/test/here it is/my file.avi" and I want to copy in another column just "my file.avi" (for the moment, after, I'll give it a try for just the path :D )

Comment: Use a here-document to solve(almost) all your quoting woes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7820049/905902

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:

```
 /usr/bin/psql -U postgres video_metadata -q -A -t -c "SELECT RIGHT(path, POSITION('\' in REVERSE(path)) -1 ) from video_file;"
```

Comment: I've answered in original post, but it fails with the '\'

Answer (score 0):

found out.... I mixed up with windows path..... it should be '/' and not '\'

complete command would be:

```
/usr/bin/psql -U postgres video_metadata -q -A -t -c "SELECT RIGHT(path, POSITION('/' in REVERSE(path)) -1 ) from video_file;"
```