# PostgreSQL - Inserting into a columns whose name is a keyword using shell script

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell, psql

I have a table named "myTable" in my PostgreSQL database which has 4 columns - `id`, `non_keyword_columnA`, `non_keyword_columnB` and `group`.

Structure of the table is as follows:

```
 Column              |    Type    |          Modifiers                                
 --------------------+------------+------------------------------------------
 id                  | integer    | not null default nextval('myTable_id_seq'::regclass)
 non_keyword_columnA | integer    | 
 non_keyword_columnB | integer    | 
 group               | integer    | not null


 Foreign-key constraints:
    "tablename_group_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("group") REFERENCES groups(id)
```

I want to insert data into this table using shell and i am using following code to do it:

`sudo /usr/sbin/chroot environment_path_here su - username -c "psql -A -z -c \"INSERT INTO myTable (non_keyword_columnA ,non_keyword_columnB ,"group") VALUES (1,2,(SELECT id from groups WHERE name='someGroupName'));\""`

I am not an expert in Databases but I understand that group is a keyword which can be used in psql queries if used with double quotes which i did in above script.

But receive error as

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "group"
> LINE 1: ...RT INTO myTable(entity,machine,group) VAL...
>                                       ^`
> ```

If I enter the environment manually and then execute the psql query then query executes successfully and row gets inserted but nothing is working through shell script.

I have tried various permutations and combinations to try as escape group keyword by using these combinations:

`sudo /usr/sbin/chroot environment_path_here su - username -c "psql -A -z -c \"INSERT INTO myTable (non_keyword_columnA ,non_keyword_columnB ,\""group"\") VALUES (231,3355,(SELECT id from groups WHERE name='releventGroupName'));\""`

`sudo /usr/sbin/chroot environment_path_here su - username -c "psql -A -z -c \"INSERT INTO myTable (non_keyword_columnA ,non_keyword_columnB ,"\"group\"") VALUES (231,3355,(SELECT id from groups WHERE name='releventGroupName'));\""`

But none of them have worked till now. I am not an expert in shell either so it may be possible that I might be making some really silly mistake here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a *here-document* as standard input for your psql.

Comment: That's one of the reasons why identifiers that require quoting are such a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Use a here-document as standard input for your psql.

(Untested:)

---

```
#!/bin/sh

(sudo /usr/sbin/chroot environment_path_here su - username -c 'psql -A -z' ) <<OMG
        INSERT INTO myTable (non_keyword_columnA ,non_keyword_columnB ,"group")
        SELECT 1,2,id
        FROM groups
        WHERE name = 'someGroupName'
        ;
OMG
```

---

[see also...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7820049/905902)